# OpenGL render float image

Tags: opengl, fragment-shader

I have a 1D float array representing a coarse 25x25 grayscale image (flattened into a 1D array), and I would like to draw it onto a square plane (sitting in 3D space), which I have drawn using the following:

```
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_glVBO ); // vertices are sitting in a VBO.
glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
glVertexPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(vec3), (void*)(0) );
glColor4f( 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f );
GLubyte indices[] = {0,1,2, // first triangle (bottom left - top left - top right)
                         0,2,3}; // second triangle (bottom left - top right - bottom right
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indices);
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );
glDisableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
```

What's an efficient way to draw said image if I intend to update this float data fairly frequently? Should I use glBindTexture on a GL_TEXTURE_1D? Or can I pass the data directly into the fragment shader and have it drawn there without binding a texture?

Comment: What's the range of the float values in the array? Are they between 0 and 1?

Comment: Floats are from 0 to 1